# How to access html resources file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, resources

I'm using VisualStudio 2008. I have a html file in my win32 project. I wonder is there a way to access html resource files. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: @eran 1.Yes i wanna access them at run time. 2. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code like this gives access to a resource

```
HANDLE handle = ::LoadLibraryEx("myapp.exe", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
HRSRC resourceHandle = ::FindResource(handle,resourceId,"resourcename");         
DWORD   size        = ::SizeofResource(handle, resourceHandle);
HGLOBAL dataHandle  = ::LoadResource(handle, resourceHandle);
void* data= ::LockResource(dataHandle);
```